# How to use jQuery plugins with AngularJs routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, validation

I have angularJs application, I also use **Angular routing** to go browse through other pages.

When I try to use some jQuery validation libraries for IE8 compatibility (for new html5 atrributes)  it does not work at all and I **guess this is because I dont use jQuery properly.**

The  the below code is from body of index.html

```
<body>
....

<script src="js/libs/jquery.h5validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function (){

      $('#Page').h5Validate();
});

</script>


</body>
```

Here "ProfilePage" form element is on another html file(consists from a div) and I can not access/use it like above using jQuery. It just does not do anything.

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you including the full jQuery, or the mini jQuery that comes with Angular?

Comment: @RGraham full version

Comment: If `ProfilePage` is on an external file loaded by a route, you should call that `h5Validate` from that controller

Comment: @ RGraham and how can I do this without creating a directive? yes bad practise..but time is short :0

Comment: Create the directive. Probably quicker than working out how not to do it with a directive.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I would put the JQuery in a controller or a directive